# how to create a html file on intellij?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, web-development-server

How should i create a html project/file on intellij and how to run it?

Detailed Steps to create a html project/file on intellij and Detailed step to how to run that file.Tried to search on internet but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick note

For Web development I advice to use WebStorm instead of IntelliJ since it's missing some features and isn't build for Web Dev specifically and when you get to using JavaScript it should be way easier.

### Current UI (default as of 09.09.23)

#### HTML Boilderplate (With everything)

Left click File on the top tab, find New and hover over it, click project and find HTML. Then you can change up some settings. After you create it find the directory with the project name on the left and find the index.html file and click twice on it to open.

Find file

[image: Find file]

Hover over new and find Project

[image: Hover over new and find Project]

Select HTML and press create.

[image: Select HTML and press create.]

Double click the file to view it if it isn't viewed already.

[image: Double click the file to view it if it isn't viewed already.]

To run it you will have a few browser icons in the top right. You could also use the green run icon, your default browser will be used. Alt+F2 is a handy shortcut to callout the menu.

[image: Click these icons to run]

#### Plain HTML

If you're a begginer you might want to not include all the files that won't be necessary for you, for that create an empty project by following the steps above but selecting Empty project instead of HTML, then right click on your directory find New, find HTML file. Technically all you have to do is to have `<!doctype html>` and  and a  but I'd reccomend using this [template](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-starter-template-a-basic-html5-boilerplate-for-index-html/)

You'll also likely have to create and link up your CSS and JS files similarly. Here's a [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-link-css-to-html/) on that

## New UI

The steps are similar for the New UI but a bit more straight forward. Click the Main Menu pop up (Alt+/ shortcut alternatively), hover over New->File->Project and select HTML in the window.

If you want a plain HTML file the steps remain unchanged from the paragraph up to. Steps to run the file remain unchaged aswell.

[image]

[image]

#### TL;DR

File (top left) -> New -> Project, select HTML/empty (if you want create a simple HTML file manually)-> Create, find and double click index.html/create a file by right clicking a directory on the left, use little browser icons on top right to run.